# Stored Procedure works in SSMS but pulls no Data in SSRS what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server

Stored Procedure works in SSMS but pulls no Data in SSRS what am I doing wrong?
I have a sp in SSMS that runs fine but apprently i am doing something wrong in SSRS because it shows no data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7CsO.jpg)

Stored Procedure used
USE [INF_EDW]
GO

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SCShippingReport]    Script 
Date: 7/14/2020 2:42:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SCShippingReport]
(@SDATE DATE,
@EDATE DATE,
@PA VARCHAR(20),
@STATUS VARCHAR(4),
@VEND VARCHAR(20),
@SHIP VARCHAR(15))

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 


  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(D, B.PRHREC, '1899-12-31') AS DATE) AS DTREC,
  case when A.PHPHR3 = ('') then ('N/A') ELSE A.PHPHR3 END PHPHR3, 
  A.PDPOID, A.PDSHPT, A.VEVEND, A.VENAME, A.PDLDSC, A.PDUOM, A.PHPRID, 
A.PDRCQT
    FROM MMS.vw_POHeaderDetail AS A WITH (NOLOCK) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
   MMS.PMPPR AS B WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON A.PDPOID = B.PRPOID AND A.PDSEQ = B.PRSEQ
WHERE (CAST(DATEADD(D, B.PRHREC, '1899-12-31') AS DATE) >= @SDATE) 
AND (CAST(DATEADD(D, B.PRHREC, '1899-12-31') AS DATE) <= @EDATE) 
AND (A.PHPSTS IN (@STATUS)) 
AND (A.PHPSTS IN ('00', '01', '10', '11', '91', '92')) 
AND (A.VEVEND = (CASE @VEND WHEN 'ALL' THEN A.VEVEND ELSE @VEND END)) 
AND (A.PHPRID = (CASE @PA WHEN 'ALL' THEN A.PHPRID ELSE @PA END)) 
AND(case when A.PHPHR3 = ('') then ('N/A') ELSE A.PHPHR3 END)  IN (@SHIP)
ORDER BY DTREC, A.PDPOID;
END
GO
```

Comment: Queries don't behave differently if they are run from different applications, meaning that your queries are not the same, as you believe.

Comment: Check credentials used to run in SSMS versus SSRS.   Might be a different set of permissions

Comment: The user has permissions to the stored Procedure  I can execute in SSMS and it runs  EXEC dbo.sp_SCShippingReport
     '01/30/2020',
     '01/31/2020',
     'ALL',
     '92',
     'ALL',
     'UPS'  Also I see that other people seems to have this issue but now sure why this is not workins in Visual Studio SSRS.  It runs with a temp table as well as plain sql just not the sp, which I wanted to use

Comment: On a different: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). There is no `B` in `PMPPR`, and `A` wouldn't be my choice to represent `vw_POHeaderDetail`. For `NOLOCK`, why are you using it? Do you actually understand it's (significant) implications?

Comment: Posting images is highly discouraged. Posting images of such low resolution that they are unreadable is just pointless.

Comment: Are you confident that SSRS is sending the correct parameters of the correct data types?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with a coworker and found that the issue was the mapping of my parameters in SSRS I had allow Multiple values, this was the issue, I changed it to not to allow multiple values and I used case statement in the query  AND (A.PHPHR3 = (CASE @SHIP WHEN 'ALL' THEN A.PHPHR3 ELSE @SHIP END)) and in the dataset for the parameter I used temp table with sorter.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ship') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ship 
CREATE TABLE #ship(PHPHR3 varchar(10)) 
INSERT INTO #ship
(PHPHR3)

SELECT DISTINCT PHPHR3
FROM    MMS.PMPPH(NOLOCK)
SELECT     PHPHR3, Sorter
FROM 
(SELECT 'ALL' AS PHPHR3, 1 AS Sorter
   UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT case when PHPHR3 = ('') then ('N/A') ELSE PHPHR3 END PHPHR3, 2 AS Sorter
                FROM  #ship) AS derivedtbl_1
ORDER BY Sorter
```

Comment: FYI, you *still* have `NOLOCK` in there (which is still a bad idea).